# split on integer values but not floating point values

Tags: java, string, split, iterator

I have a java program where I need to split on integer values but not floating point values

ie. `"1/\\2"` should produce: `[1,/\\,2]`
but `"1.0/\\2.0"` should produce: `[1.0,/\\,2.0]`

does anybody have any ideas?

or could anybody point me in the direction of how to split on the specific strings `"\\/"` and `"/\\"` ?

UPDATE: sorry! one more case! for the string "100 /\ 3.4e+45" I need to split it into:
 [100,/\,3.4,e,+,45]

my current regex is (kind of really ugly):

```
line.split("\\s+|(?<=[-+])|(?=[-+])|(?:(?<=[0-9])(?![0-9.]|$))|(?:(?<![0-9.]|^)(?=[0-9]))|(?<=[-+()])|(?=[-+()])|(?<=e)|(?=e)");
```

and for the string: "100 /\ 3.4e+45" is giving me:
 [100,/\,3.4,+,45]

Comment: What should it produce if `.` isn't the decimal separator for the current locale?

Comment: public String[] split(String regex) this is the signature of split  you could pass "V"  or "/\" to split the values . I still not clear on the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should do it:

```
(?:(?<=[0-9])(?![0-9.]|$))|(?:(?<![0-9.]|^)(?=[0-9]))
```

It's two checks, basically matching:

1. A digit not followed by a digit, a decimal point, or the end of text.
2. A digit not preceded by a digit, a decimal point, or the start of text.

It will match the empty space after/before the digit, so you can use this regex in `split()`.

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bN3rG0/1) for demo.

---

**Follow-up**

> could anybody point me in the direction of how to split on the specific strings "\/" and "/\""

If you want to split before a specific pattern, use a *positive lookahead*: `(?=xxx)`. If you want to split after a specific pattern, use a *positive lookbehind*: `(?<=xxx)`. To do either, separate by `|`:

```
(?<=xxx)|(?=xxx)
```

where `xxx` is the *text* `\/` or `/\`, i.e. the regex `\\/|/\\`, and doubling for Java string literal:

```
"(?<=\\\\/|/\\\\)|(?=\\\\/|/\\\\)"
```

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kL1tO6/1) for demo.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
    String regex = "\\d+(.\\d+)?", str = "1//2";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    int index = 0;
    for(index = 0 ; m.find() ; index = m.end()) {
        if(index != m.start()) list.add(str.substring(index, m.start()));
        list.add(str.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
    }

    list.add(str.substring(index));
```

The idea is to find number using `regex` and `Matcher`, and also add the strings in between.